# Logout from LXDE session after last application exits

Tags: x11, lxde, kiosk

Is there any way to automate the above?
Currently I have the following autostart file in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` and would  like LXDE to exit the session after chromium exits but don't know how.

```
@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk http://127.0.0.1:80807
```

**What I already tried:**

1. Changing the last line to:

   ```
   @chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk http://127.0.0.1:8080; lxsession-logout
   ```

   This only lead to chromium opening another website - and if it
   would work the way I expected it to do, it would still show the logout
   dialogue.
2. Using a .Xsession instead of a complete LXDE Session

   This had the desired effect of logging out after closing chromium, but as a side effect a RealVNC popup showed up.
   (I found no way to disable this.)

   The .Xsession file was nearly identical to the above `autostart` file except the `@`'s and additional arguments to chromium for window dimensions and placement

**Why I want to achieve this:**

My goal is to have a Raspberry Pi Kiosk Setup with the following requirements:

- It should have two users, one of which is passwordless and unprivileged (`kiosk`) and the other is privileged (`pi`).
- I want the user to be able to login as `kiosk`, but also be able to reach the login screen if I need to change something as `pi`.
- If chromium crashes I want the user to not be stuck in an empty LXDE shell with no way of exiting. (This would currently be the case.)

If you know how to achieve this in another way also please feel free to answer.